# Implications of allowing users to email content and attachments to a server

Tags: spring, security, email, jpa, amazon-web-services

I have implemented a feature in my application that allows registered users to send an email to a gmail account, which my server polls using Spring Integration, and then if it recognises the sender, stores the subject and body content in a database (via JPA).

I also want to allow users to be able to send files as attachments to these emails which I plan to store on AWS.

I'm sure there must be security implications with both of these features, but I'm not aware of what they might be.

So my question is, what are the security implications of allowing users to store email content in my DB and attached files on AWS?

TIA

Comment: You didn't say what you want to make further with the attachments... Also think, how important it is to store the data on servers in your own country.

Comment: I don't want to do anything with them, just store them for the users for their reference at a later date, so I won't be opening them, just passing them to AWS for storage.  I'm not sure the location of the file matters, as long as they are secure.

Answer (score 0):

You could have some problems when you will have many emails to process using a single email account (probably not a problem at the beginning). Also making yourself dependent on an external email provider may sound for you clients really unreliable (depending on your clients/business). Also someone could eat up all your space on gmail by sending too many emails that don't get deleted on time. Also when storing the files in AWS you must store the files with random filenames. Probably you will have to read some tutorials for that.